# How to get number total of word that i explode using php?

Tags: php, explode

How to get number total of word that i explode using php ?

this is my code for explode value from `$multi_text`, i want to know how can i get number total of word after explode finished using php ?

in this case = 12

```
<?PHP
$multi_text  = "aaa sss ddd fff rrr eee www sss fff ggg hhh ttt";
$pieces = explode(" ", $multi_text);
?>
```

Comment: use `echo count($pieces);`

Comment: What does `explode` return? Use that to rephrase the question - and then answer it for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `explode()` product is stored as array. So use `count()` to get the size of array:

```
echo count($pieces);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count for this:

```
$numberOfWords = count($pieces)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count it using `count()` function in **PHP**. it will count all array inside the variable. 
Try:

```
<?PHP
    $multi_text  = "aaa sss ddd fff rrr eee www sss fff ggg hhh ttt";
    $pieces = explode(" ", $multi_text);

    echo '<pre>';
    echo print_r($pieces);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Total words : ' . count($pieces);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `explode()` function return a array.

So, you can use `count($array)`  or `sizeof($array)`.

Both are use for get number of array elements.

Actually, `sizeof()` — Alias of `count()`